# MemoryLeak through onConfigurationChanged()

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I have an AsyncTask which I need to "restart" if the user does configurations such as Switch Color.

When he do so I start the AsyncTask like this:

```
myWorkerClass.clearMemory();
    myWorkerClass = new WorkerClass(getApplicationContext(), gv, searchbar, width, scaleButtonText);
    myWorkerClass.execute();
```

In the `AsyncTask` I add a `onTextChangeListener` to my EditText!(Which causes the MemoryLeak later).

To prevent MemoryLeaks I have a Method in my AsyncTask which removes the `onTextChangedListener`:

```
public void clearMemory() {
    searchbar.removeTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher);
}
```

Everything works fine except when I rotate my device. When I rotate my Device I do only this in `onConfigurationChanged`:

```
myWorkerClass.clearMemory();
            myWorkerClass = new WorkerClass(getApplicationContext(), gv, searchbar, width, scaleButtonText);
            myWorkerClass.execute();
```

As you can see I do exactly the same thing as if the user changes a Color. **But** at rotating device I'm leaking Memory, at switching Color I'm not!

**This is after switching the Color:**

[image]

**This is after rotating the Screen a few times (remember I do exactly the same as at switching color:**

[image]

**These are my Leak Suspects from the Heap Dump:**

[image]

[image]

**This is my dominator tree:**
[image]

**Why do I know the onTextChangeListener is the Problem?**

Because if I comment adding a onTextChangedListener to my EditText out, everything works fine. No Memory Leaks.

**My Question:**

Why does a Rotation Change leak Memory and a Color Change does not when I start the asynctask the exact same way and do exact the same things within the asynctask?

I searched a little bit: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

But I can't figure out if that is my Problem. The Rotation must do something different, like creating a new activity because of that creating a new reference to my edittext. And because of that he can't remove the old `onTextChangeListener`.

Please understand. I don't want to make my whole code public. But I think this isn't necessary anyway in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Rotation must do something different, like creating a new activity because of that creating a new reference to my edittext.

exactly, it destroys your current activity and creates a new one. If `searchbar` is a member variable of your AsyncTask then consider putting it into WeakReference:

```
WeakReference<SearchBar> searchbarPtr;
```

then access using searchBarPtr.get(), but check if its null, if so then it means it was garbage collected due to config change.

Also remember to not make your AsyncTask an inner class of you activity. If it is nested then make it static. Otherwise your asynctask will keep reference to your activity and it will prevent it from being destroyed - until its thread ends.

Unfortuanately making it all work corectly in all situations can be quite difficult and time consuming.

Hopefully no one will suggest preventing destruction of your activity through android:configChanges, implementing correct behaviour of your activity during rotation will prevent it from crashing/leaking in less common activity lifecycle moments which cannot be prevented by android:configChanges.

Comment: Thank you for your answere. Yes, i put the reference of my searchbar(from my activity) to the AsyncTask(which is not an inner class of my activity). So i never worked with WeakReference can you give me a quick solution how to implement this? I know it's not easy due that i didn't provide any code. But maybe we can give it a shot? Anyway if he is GCing my searchbar, then my `clearMemory()` must be useless right? Because with collecting the searchbar he also collects the `onTextChangeListener`, right?

Comment: @MMike I have added short pseudocode presentation of WeakReference usage. Also in Activity.onCreate you can update searchBar reference inside your AsyncTask, but your will have to keep reference to your asynctask somehow, by using (deprecated) onRetainNonConfigurationInstance, or new aproach with retained fragments.

Comment: Hm this is too big for me, i will try with WeakReference and put the WeakReference to the AsyncTask and check if it's null. If it's null i Need to make a new reference to the searchbar right and put it again into a WeakReference if it's necessary?

Comment: @MMike Yes, make new reference inside Activity.onCreate. Depending on what your async task is doing, you can just ditch it and create a new AsyncTask in Activity.onCreate after rotation - this is IMO preferable. In onDestroy cancel current AsyncTask - inside of it you can check it with isCancelled(), if it is true then stop all operations and cancel prcessing in onPostExecute. If your AsyncTask is doing something long, then consider using Services - ie. IntentService, and ie. use broadcasts to show progress in activity.

Answer (score 0):

In android, the rotation destroys your current activity to start a new one.
To avoid it, you can add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in your manifest file.

Below are tips to avoid memory leaks on Rotation change

1. Do not keep long-lived references to a context-activity (a reference to an activity should have the same life cycle as the activity itself)
2. Try using the context-application instead of a context-activity
3. Avoid non-static inner classes in an activity if you don't control their life cycle, use a static inner class and make a weak reference to the activity inside. The solution to this issue is to use a static inner class with a WeakReference to the outer class, as done in ViewRoot and its W inner class for instance
4. A garbage collector is not an insurance against memory leaks

Source: [Avoiding memory leaks](http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)

Comment: Thank you for your Response Lazy Ninja. I only pass the ApplicationContext, my AsyncTask is not an inner class of my activity and my only Memory leak is my `addTextChangeListener` of the `EditText`searchbar. I don't want to get rid of the Rotation, i want to get rid of the leak. But i have no idea how to do that. Is there no method which get's called before the activity gets destroyed and recreated? UpDate: `="orientation|screenSize"` doesn't help. I'm leaking Memory again!

Comment: @MMike `Is there no method which get's called before the activity gets destroyed and recreated?`, onDestroy -> just before it gets destoryed, onCreate -> will be called for new recreated activity.