# Prevent my MemoryLeak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-asynctask

i already come closer to solve my Memory leak by asking this question:

[MemoryLeak trough onConfigurationChanged()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435134/memoryleak-trough-onconfigurationchanged)

Now i know that my leak is caused by recreating the activity due to Rotation of the device.

I'm creating a reference to my `searchbar` in my activity:

```
searchbar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_searchbar);
```

and pass this reference to my `AsyncTask` which is not an inner class of my `Activity`:

```
myWorkerClass.clearMemory();
    myWorkerClass = new WorkerClass(getApplicationContext(), gv, searchbar, width, scaleButtonText);
    myWorkerClass.execute();
```

In my `AsyncTask` i add a `onTextChangedListener` to my `searchbar`:

```
searchbar.addTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher);
```

When a orientation Change happens, i Need to call the `AsyncTask` again. To prevent MemoryLeaks i call `clearMemory` before which is a method of my `AsyncTask`:

```
public void clearMemory() {
    searchbar.removeTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher);

}
```

**The Problem**
When `onConfigurationChange()` is called. I already got a new `Activity` created by the OS.
That means my original reference to the searchbar isn't accessible/existing for me anymore.
Therefore my `clearMemory` doesn't remove the `textChangedListener` from my searchbar...
And then i start the `AsyncTask` again which adds another `onTextChangedListener` to my searchbar creating my **Memory Leak**.

**My Question**

How can i prevent this. (I would be really thankful for a code-snippet with a short Explanation).

How can i get the old reference after a new activity has been created. Or how can i call `clearMemory()` short time before a new Activity has been created by the OS due to Rotation of the device.

I Appreciated any help.

**Update**

Sorry i forgot to add my approaches to solve this issue:

I also tried to create a `WeakReference`:

```
WeakReference<EditText> myWeakReference = new WeakReference<EditText>(searchbar)
```

and put the reference to the `AsyncTask` like this:

```
myWorkerClass = new WorkerClass(getApplicationContext(), gv, myWeakReference.get(), width, scaleButtonText);
    myWorkerClass.execute();
```

Comment: What are you using the AsyncTask for and why does it need a reference to the search bar?

Comment: Read about WeakReference in JAVA, you can pass a weak reference of searchbar(EditText) to Async task. Even cleaner approach can be, not to pass the searchbar (EditText) atall to Async class.

Comment: It sounds like you have a series of operations that are out of order. I would start there.

Comment: @Kelevandos i Need to searchbar to add a `TextChangeListener` and this listener Need `myTextWatcher`. And `myTextWatcher` Need Access to variable like Images which i get in the `doInBackground`. That's why i Need the searchbar in the `AsyncTask` and thats why i have an `AsnycTask`. `Notice:` Getting the Images i Need is a short term process, that's why i have choosen the `AsyncTask`. Thank you for your response

Comment: @Eu.Dr. I tried to only pass the weakreference of my searchbar. But it changed nothing. The Leak appears again and again.... Don't know what i'm doing wrong

Comment: @Mr.Concolato Where?

Comment: @MMike I thnik you have the architecture wrong. Make the TextWatcher invoke AsyncTasks to obtain stuff you nees, but keep the rest on the UI Thread

Comment: @Kelevandos you mean, i should create the `TextWatcher` in my `AsyncTask` pass back the reference of my `TextWatcher` to my `Activity` and add the `onTextChangedListener` in my Activity? That way i don't have to pass the searchbar to the `AsyncTask`?

Comment: See my answer, I hope I made it clear enough

Answer (score 0):

Create the SearchBar and TextWatcher on UI Thread and only invoke AsyncTasks in the TextWatcher when you need to obtain something (preferably passing some kind of listener to it). Like this:

```
SearchBar searchBar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_searchbar);
searchBar.addTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher);

public class myTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    afterTextChanged(){
        /*   Invoke the AsyncTask here so it can retrieve data and return it through some listener /*

    }

}
```

Please also try adding the below parameter to your  tag in the Manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|navigation|uiMode"
```

It should prevent the activity from dying completely.

Comment: Thank you for your answere. But that way, my `AsyncTask` gets invoked evertime user is trying to search trough my "activity-Content". I don't want that. The `AsyncTask` should only be invoked at the beginning(everything works fine) after for example a Color Change by the user (works fine) or after a configuration Change(Memory leak). Can you confirm my Argument?

Comment: Well, the leak is clearly caused BY the fact you pass the SearchBar reference to the AsyncTask (therefore passing it to another Thread). I think that instead of thinking about this particular leak, you should rather redesign the flow here, to avoid that altogether.

Comment: I have another idea, please see my answer

Comment: Tried your second idea - same issue. Memory Leak. I also tried to make the `TextWatcher` static and that way didn't Need to pass the searchbar and added the `onTextChangedListener`on the UI-Thred - Memory Leak. Why should it be different on the UI Thread? If the Activity gets destroyed my UI-Thread get's destroyed as well. So my reference to searchbar must be gone anyway? Or not?